# Dynamically filter flowFiles based on data from table

Tags: arrays, json, stream, filtering, apache-nifi

I'm trying to using NIFI dynamically filter flowFiles in JSON format and keep only those values that are present is one SQL table.

I'm using QueryRecord processor, with query like:
SELECT *
FROM FLOWFILE
WHERE ${key} = ${value}

only those values that are present in QueryDatabaseTable variables should be kept.

FlowFiles to be filtered looks like these:
 `[ { "CustomerID" : 1, "OrderNbr" : "12", "Amount":100 } ]`

CustomerID field is the one to check and filter data.

[image: current nifi flow]

Comment: what is the question?

Comment: How to write SQL query to filter it out? My current query: SELECT * FROM FLOWFILE
WHERE Customer_AccountID = ${value}